# LWJGL GLWF glfwInit() function stuck

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I re-imported some code to IntelliJ (few months old) and wanted to use Maven to handle my dependencies. So I added all neccessary LWJGL dependecies to my pom.xml (copied the genereated pom from the LWJGL-configurator). 
When I now run the code, the program gets stuck at glfwInit() for about 30 seconds before going on. LWJGL debug says it has loaded the glfw-library, and then the program hangs. This code worked fine when I first imported the natives myself.

What could cause glfwInit to hang for 30 seconds?

```
GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not initialize glfw");

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS,24);
```

Comment: Is the lwjgl you requested in your `pom.xml` the very same version of the one where you imported the natives yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. 
I also compiled my program natively (Kotlin) and observed the same issue.
I also observed that this behaviour is not displayed on my friends computer.

Thus, it is reasonable to say that LWJGL has nothing to do with it, and that it is instead bound to individual systems. I have not found an answer as to why it happens anywhere.

The problem got worse over time for me.